# Thorntail + Lombok builder fails

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, lombok, thorntail

Our Torntail 2.3.0 application with cdi, microprofile-config, jaxrs and undertow dependencies fails when using lombok `@Builder`.

```
2019-02-04 09:36:27,544 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2019-02-04 09:36:27,544 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitNestHostExperimental(ClassVisitor.java:158)
2019-02-04 09:36:27,544 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:541)
2019-02-04 09:36:27,544 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:391)
2019-02-04 09:36:27,545 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.internal.JAXRSArchiveImpl.isJAXRS(JAXRSArchiveImpl.java:119)
2019-02-04 09:36:27,545 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.internal.JAXRSArchiveImpl.isJAXRS(JAXRSArchiveImpl.java:96)
2019-02-04 09:36:27,545 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.JAXRSArchive.isJAXRS(JAXRSArchive.java:55)
2019-02-04 09:36:27,545 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.internal.DefaultJAXRSWarDeploymentFactory.create(DefaultJAXRSWarDeploymentFactory.java:46)
2019-02-04 09:36:27,545 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.deployments.DefaultDeploymentCreator.createDefaultDeployment(DefaultDeploymentCreator.java:69)
```

This is probably due to the missing empty constructor in the generated Builder inner-classes by lombok. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Judging from `visitNestHostExperimental`, do you perhaps use Java 11? Thorntail 2.3.0 still only supports Java 8, though Java 11 support is coming soon.

Comment: We do use Java 11 which other than this Lombok.Builder issue works correctly